# matching as preprocessing tool in R

Tags: r, matching, data-wrangling

I want to use coarsened exact matching as a preprocessing tool in R. I decided to use the `cem()` function. I successfully matched my data, but the function only produces a `cem.match` objekt. My question is how do I get from this `cem.match` object to a matched dataset, which I can use for further regression analysis?

My steps so far:

````
matched<- cem(treatment = "CG", data = MyData, drop = colnames(MyData[1:16,19:29,31]) ,keep.all=TRUE)

MyData_matched <- pair(matched, MyData)```
````